# Xamarin Android Google Map - Add marker where user clicks

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms, I am using a custom renderer in Android for a map I have implemented using `Android.Gms.Maps` I want to write functionality that adds a marker in the area a user clicked on the map.

```
    public async void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        map.MapClick+= HandleMapClick;
    }
```

In my `HandleMapClick()` function, how do I use the `addMarker()` function to add a marker to the area which a user clicked on the map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GoogleMap.MapClickEventArgs` contains a "Point" that contains the lat/long of the user' click. Create a `MarkerOption`, assign it that point and add it to your map.

```
googleMap.MapClick += (object sender, GoogleMap.MapClickEventArgs e) =>
{
    using (var markerOption = new MarkerOptions())
    {
        markerOption.SetPosition(e.Point);
        markerOption.SetTitle("StackOverflow");
        // save the "marker" variable returned if you need move, delete, update it, etc...
        var marker = googleMap.AddMarker(markerOption);
    }
};
```